# MySQL password unknown in LAMP stack on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: mysql, ssh, google-cloud-platform, lamp

I just start using Google Cloud Platform today and I create a LAMP stack machine, which run Debian 8, following Google they dont give any support for it and I'm trying to figure out which was the password they put on my SU and the password they put on the MySQL database.

Anyone has a idea?

I tryed using my own google password for superuser without any success.

Thank you for reading and replying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Deployment manager on Google Play, https://console.cloud.google.com/dm/deployments, click your deployment and on the right side you will see the following: MySQL password (Temporary)

Comment: thank you, i already solve the problem but forgot to asign the success answer

Answer (score 0):

On the properties and info of the VM (Lamp Stack), in my case lamp-1 you can found the password autogenerated with the name mysqlRootPassword